# Is there a simple way of changing magentos tax to only round down to the nearest penny?

Tags: php, magento, math, magento-1.8

Hi I am just wondering is there an easy way to get the tax in magento to only round down no matter what the last number is. for example:

12.56 will stay 12.56 
12.563 will round down to 12.56 
12.569 will round down to 12.56

no matter what the ending is i want it to round down i am only using php for this here is an example of code that i tried to use it works for most prices but on one price it rounds it down even thou it is a whole number. this is my code so far sorry about bad english.

```
<?php
 const TaxRate = 20;

class ThomasDudley_Tax_Calculation extends Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation
{
    public function CalcTaxAmount ($Price, $TaxRate, $PriceIncludeTax = false, $Round = true)
    {

    $TaxRate = $TaxRate/100;

    if ($PriceIncludeTax) {
        $amount = $Price*(1-1/(1+$TaxRate));
    } else {
        $amount = $Price*$TaxRate;
    }

     if ($round) {
        return $this->roundDown($amount);
    } else {
        return $this->roundDown($amount);
    }


    function roundDown($amount)
    {

        if ($amount > 0.005) return round($amount - 0.005,2);

        } elseif {          
                 ($amount < -0.005) return round($amount + 0.005,2);
        else return 0.0;
    }
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening here, this is a slight miscalculation on my behalf i was looking at the vat and calculation wrong at first i thought it was just 20% of the overall answer but its not my magento was setup so that the vat is worked out each line, So when i worked out the vat by each line it would be correct. thanks the solutions you showed me this will come in handy later on in my projects life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

How about some clever use of floor()

```
function roundDown($amount)
{ 
   //This can be wrapped up into one line, but for the sake of showing the process.
   $tmpamt = $amount * 100; //Shift the decimal point
   $newamt = floor($tmpamt); 
   return $newamt / 100; 
}
```

So with your example of 12.569:

```
1. $tmpamt is set to 1256.9 
2. $newamt is set to 1256
3. function returns 12.56
```

Comment: Just wondering would this work correct if it is multiple objects for example 12.56 + 10.24 + 35.86 would this still calculate the rounded down process correctly on these ammounts.

Comment: this did work but i found with a certain set of results it still rounds up the price in total is £10,192.08 and then it is calculating the vat at 20% this is the part of the code i want it to round down the vat is worked out at £2,038.42 when it should be £2,038.41 i know its 1P but this has to be 100% accurate any ideas or thoughts ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "multiple objects". Are you adding them before calling the function? 

Then it should work. I tested the function with 10192.08 and I got the correct response, but it's worth mention that if it has to be "100% accurate", you probably shouldn't be using floats.

Comment: the multiple objects i figured out wouldn't be apart of this thats something else, i have changed the function to what you said and when it has been calculated it still rounds up to the next penny i have tried this with a couple numbers its the same when using the numbers £5,243.28 the vat says it is £1,048.66 i worked this out on a calculator and the answer i got was 1048.656 so this should round down to 1048.65 not .66 any ideas or would you say its another piece of code causing this ??

Comment: It could be several things. Verify that the amount you're originally passing into the rounddown function is really what you expect it to be: php floats can be unpredictable. I'm not getting any error, but I'm feeding it the cost directly from what you tell me, so there might be something in your code before the rounddown() that's off. 

It's a trivial function, so if you're not getting the output you expect, I would look to the input first.

Comment: the inputs are correct because there are being brought in by a vantage system all the user specifies is the quantity of the product so the prices are always correct and then this is the tax code that takes the amounts from the vantage system after they have been added together to get the overall price it works out the vat and then adds this to the price the part that i am trying to get to round down is the vat but it looks like it rounds up when the last digit is above 5

Comment: Then I'd check the values inside the function before returning. Make sure it's taking $amount correctly, and the results of each step are what they're supposed to be.

Comment: how would i check this because when i echo all of the functions to the screen then it looks like everything is done twice and it only shows the prices for the 2 sections are shown but the vat is not. any suggestions ??